# problemas al instalar Adminlte en laravel

Tags: laravel, composer

recien me conecto nuevamente, tengo un problema para instalar el paquete de Adminlte,
instalo todo bien el composer

```
composer global require "acacha/adminlte-laravel-installer=~3.0"
```

pero al parecer al ejecutar el comando

```
adminlte-laravel install
```

me arroja este error, cualquier informacion haganmelo saber es laravel 5.6

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Config\Repository' not 
>  found in C:\Users\Administrador
> ```
>
> ITMS\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\acacha\llum\src\Console\LlumCommand.php:256
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 C:\Users\Administrador ITMS\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\acacha\llum\src\Console\LlumCommand.php(114):
>   Acacha\Llum\Console\LlumCommand->obtainConfig()
>       #1 C:\Users\Administrador ITMS\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\acacha\llum\llum(20):
>   Acacha\Llum\Console\LlumCommand->__construct()
>       #2 {main}
>         thrown in C:\Users\Administrador ITMS\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\acacha\llum\src\Console\LlumCommand.php
>   on line 256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compañeros consegui la respuesta gracias

en el archivo AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider.php

debemos cambiar

`use Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;`

por

```
use Illuminate\Console\DetectsApplicationNamespace;
```

Comment: recuerda que en cuanto te sea posible aceptes tu propia respuesta para que les sirva a otros usuarios que tengan la misma duda